# sceneform - camera view is so lag after rendering the 3D model

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm a newbie in AR for Android. I face a question that I render a 3D model on the flat table, and my camera view is so lag if the 3D model appears in the camera view, but if 3D model does not appear in camera view, the camera view is smooth. The image below is the memory usage.

[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZiCr.png)

here is the code that I load my 3D model

```
ModelRenderable mRenderable;
RenderableSource urSrc = RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
            this,
            Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/mymodel/model.gltf"),
            RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
        .setScale(0.5f)
        .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
        .build();

ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, urSrc)
        .build()
        .thenAccept(renderable -> {
            mRenderable = renderable;
        })
```

What cause this problem & how to deal with this problem?

Used Device: Samsung A51 5G
3D model type: GLTF, about 100M (include all material)

Comment: The default lighting method is usually overkill in ARCore for a model that size...

Comment: @YinOrYan you are right. When I disable the lighting, it looks better than before, but still a little bit lag. Thank you~

Comment: 100M model might be a bit big. But what is important is how many polygons the model has. You can try and reduce the model size in blender or any other modeling tool